# Qt on Mac OS X: How to get rid of QListView's blue outline?

Tags: c++, python, css, macos, qt

I am using a `QListView` with custom background image and I want to get rid of the blue outline-border that appears around QListView on OS X.

I tried styling it with:

```
border: 0 none;
outline: 0 none;
border-collapse: collapse;
```

But it still appears.

What do I need to do to get rid of this blue hue?

Comment: `outline-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);` might do it.

Comment: Thank you @KyleSevenoaks but it did not work. ;-(

Comment: Hm. transparent might work also?

Comment: Unfortunately it still keeps the blue highlight and there does not seem to be much about it even on Google either. Thank you for trying to help though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This should work:

```
yourListView->setAttribute(Qt::WA_MacShowFocusRect, false);
```